# Broken links (404 and 500 resposecode) throwing "ok" message when running on selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to verify all the broken links (404 and 500) in the application... I researched and tried to run a script..I see all the links displays "ok" message irrespective of whether the links are broken..Any help would be highly appreciated..

```
    List<WebElement> links = myD.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    System.out.println("Total links are " + links.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
        WebElement sle = links.get(i);
        String url = sle.getAttribute("href");
        verifyLinkActive(url);

    }
}


public static void verifyLinkActive(String linkUrl) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(linkUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnect = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnect.setConnectTimeout(3000);
        httpURLConnect.connect();
        if (httpURLConnect.getResponseCode() == 200) {
            System.out.println(linkUrl + " - " + httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage());
        }

    if (httpURLConnect.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND) {
            System.out.println(linkUrl + " -" + httpURLConnect.getResponseMessage() + " - " + HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);*/
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in Katalon studio (groovy). This works fine:

```
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate

import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext
import javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager
import javax.security.cert.CertificateException

import java.net.SocketTimeoutException
import java.net.ConnectException

import org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword
import com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil

public class LinkChecker {

    @Keyword
    def trustAllCerts() {
        TrustManager trustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
                    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return null
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
                }
    }

    @Keyword
    def hitLinks(ArrayList<String> links) {
        ArrayList<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<List<String>>()
        ArrayList<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>()
        for (String link: links) {
            if (isValidUrl(link)) {
                urls.add(new URL(link))
            }
        }
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = trustAllCerts()
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom())
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())
        HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid)
        for (URL url: urls) {
            CharSequence u = String.valueOf(url)
            if (!u.contains("#") || !u.contains("/-/")) {
                try {
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
                    connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
                    connection.setFollowRedirects(false)
                    connection.setDoOutput(true)
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(20000)
                    int statusCode
                    try {
                        statusCode = connection.getResponseCode()
                    }
                    catch (SSLHandshakeException sslHandshakeEx) {
                        KeywordUtil.markWarning("Unable to hit url: " + url + "due to SSLHandshakeException.")
                    }
                    Map<String, List<String>> responseHeadersMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()
                    if (statusCode != null) {
                        responseHeadersMap = connection.getHeaderFields()
                    }
                    String responseContentType
                    if (!responseHeadersMap.isEmpty() && responseHeadersMap.get("Content-Type") != null) {
                        responseContentType = responseHeadersMap.get("Content-Type")
                    }
                    else {
                        KeywordUtil.markWarning("Content-Type not found in response. Response headers:" + System.lineSeparator()
                                + stringifyHeaders(responseHeadersMap))
                    }
                    if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400) {
                        if (responseContentType != null) {
                            KeywordUtil.logInfo(url.toString() + System.lineSeparator() + "status code: " + String.valueOf(statusCode) + ", content type: " + responseContentType)
                        }
                        else {
                            KeywordUtil.logInfo(url.toString() + System.lineSeparator() + "status code: " + String.valueOf(statusCode) + ", content type: not found")
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        KeywordUtil.markWarning(url.toString() + ", status code: " + String.valueOf(statusCode))
                    }
                    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(url, statusCode, responseContentType))
                    results.add(result)
                    connection.disconnect()
                }
                catch (ConnectException | SocketTimeoutException connectionException) {
                    KeywordUtil.markWarning("Unable to hit url: " + url + " due to ConnectException.")
                }
            }
        }
        return results
    }

    @Keyword
    def isValidUrl(String url) {
        Boolean isValid = false
        UrlValidator urlValidator = new UrlValidator()
        isValid = urlValidator.isValid(url)
        return isValid
    }

    @Keyword
    def stringifyHeaders(Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        ArrayList<String> adepts = new ArrayList<String>()
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry: map.entrySet()) {
            String adept = entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue()
            adepts.add(adept)
        }

        return String.join(System.lineSeparator(), adepts)
    }

    @Keyword
    def getLinkContentType(String link) {
        URL url
        ArrayList<String> toReturn = new ArrayList<String>()
        if (isValidUrl(link)) {
            url = new URL(link)
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = trustAllCerts()
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL")
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom())
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory())
            HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
                        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid)
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
            connection.setFollowRedirects(false)
            connection.setDoOutput(true)
            connection.setConnectTimeout(120000)
            int statusCode
            try {
                statusCode = connection.getResponseCode()
            }
            catch (SSLHandshakeException | ConnectException connectionError) {
                KeywordUtil.markWarning("Unable to hit link " + url)
            }
            Map<String, List<String>> responseHeadersMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>()
            if (statusCode != null) {
                responseHeadersMap = connection.getHeaderFields()
            }
            String responseContentType
            if (!responseHeadersMap.isEmpty() && responseHeadersMap.get("Content-Type") != null) {
                responseContentType = String.valueOf(responseHeadersMap.get("Content-Type"))
            }
            else {
                KeywordUtil.markWarning("Content-Type not found in response. Response headers:" + System.lineSeparator()
                        + stringifyHeaders(responseHeadersMap))
            }
            if (statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400) {
                if (responseContentType != null) {
                    String ct = responseContentType.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
                    List<String> cts = ct.split(";")
                    toReturn.addAll(cts)
                }
            }
            connection.disconnect()
        }
        else {
            KeywordUtil.markError("Collected invalid link: " + link)
        }
        return toReturn
    }

}
```